# Mocha expected at most once, invoked twice, but method is clearly invoked only once

Tags: ruby, testing, mocking, expectations, ruby-mocha

I'm using Mocha for mock testing. Below is the relevant code:

```
# test_player.rb
should "not download the ppg more than once for a given year" do
  @durant.expects(:fetch_points_per_game).at_most_once
  ppg = @durant.points_per_game
  ppg2= @durant.points_per_game
  assert_equal ppg, ppg2, "A player should have a points per game"
end

# player.rb
class Player
  # ...

  def points_per_game(year=Date.today.year)
    @points_per_game ||= fetch_points_per_game(year)
  end
  alias_method :ppg, :points_per_game

  private

  def fetch_points_per_game(year=Date.today.year)
    31.2
  end
end
```

The test failed, complaining that there was an "unexpected invocation: #.fetch_points_per_game(any_parameters)"

My understanding of my code is if @point_per_game is nil, fetch_points_per_game will be called, otherwise, the result is cached for future calls to points_per_game. So why is the test complaining that fetch_points_per_game was called twice?

Answer (score 3):

In your expectation, you're not specifying a return value, so the stubbed call returns nil.  This is why it's being called a second time.  If you change the expectation to:

```ruby
@durant.expects(:fetch_points_per_game).at_most_once.returns(1.23)
```

You should find that the tests now pass.